# run single object file in gdb

Tags: gdb

I have a .o file lying around encompassing the compiled code of a single function, that i don't have the source to. Is it possible to run this in `gdb` somehow? Would it help to write a wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can run it if you write a wrapper, for example something like:

```c
extern int foo();
int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

Obviously using the appropriate prototype.
Then link this with the object you have, for example by `gcc -g -o wrapper wrapper.c foo.o`